# Permutations of first 10 natural numbers such that all the prefix sums are distinct

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

This is a question that I was asked in a Quant Interview. I would like you all to have a crack at this. I could not find a problem similar in any way to this on the internet.

> Given the first 10 natural numbers: $1, 2, \ldots 10 $. Find $6$ permutations of these numbers:
>
> $$a_{1,1}, \; a_{1,2}, \ldots a_{1, 10}$$
> $$a_{2, 1},\; a_{2,2}, \ldots a_{2, 10}$$
> $$a_{3, 1},\; a_{3,2}, \ldots a_{3, 10}$$
> $$a_{4, 1},\; a_{4,2}, \ldots a_{4, 10}$$
> $$a_{5, 1},\; a_{5,2}, \ldots a_{5, 10}$$
> $$a_{6, 1},\; a_{6,2}, \ldots a_{6, 10}$$
> such that the sums of the prefixes of lengths $1, 2, \ldots 9$ of the $6$ permutations are distinct.

What I could notice in the problem was that the number of sums that we are supposed to make distinct is $9 \times 6 = 54$ and the last sum i.e. the sum of all the numbers will be the same for every permutation i.e. equal to $55$.

Hence, we can target every number from $1, 2, \ldots 54$ successively and try to create permutations in that manner. However, I am unable to prove/disprove whether this sort of construction will be possible for any 6 initial values (one for each permutation).

P.S. Lucky for me, $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ do make a valid set of the initial choices and I could construct the 6 permutations. However, the interviewer wasn't very impressed with the solution and asked me to think of a smarter way.

Any help is appreciated :)

**EDIT:**

I made some kind of observation on the problem. Suppose we have a certain choice of numbers for the $j^{th}$ column of the permutations i.e. the set ${a_{1, j}, \ldots a_{6, j}}$, we can arrange the same values in the reverse order in the column $10-j+1$.

This would ensure that we have the same total sum left among the remaining numbers. I could not make any formal proof that this would work but I believe this could help.

Comment: There's a (many) sets of initial choices that will not work. EG Show that you need both 1 and 2 in the initial set.

Comment: That is alright. I can imagine there would be many of those. I am looking for, in fact, a much more systematic solution than what I proposed in the question itself.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your solution? IE Is it a pure "guess and check" with little motivation? Were there general ideas guiding what you were doing?

Comment: @CalvinLin I started with {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} as my first number for each permutation respectively. Now, I look to target the sum 7. Note, that it is important to target the sums in an increasing manner or else if we skip any sum, there won't be a way to cover that later. So, I added 6 in the first 5 permutations. Now, 6 can not be added to the last permutation, so we target the sum 13, and come back to 12 later. That is how I continued.

Comment: @bigbang: I do not see that strategy succeeding. I cannot place 37.